# Удаление текста, если введено больше чем в "substringToIndex:"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Спасибо за вчерашнюю помощь, но вот только сейчас заметила, что если ввести меньше чем 51, то приложение крашится

> NSString *string = [yourLabel text];
>
> [yourLabel setText: [string substringToIndex: 51]];

А как сделать, чтоб был откат к 51, если введено БОЛЬШЕ, чем 51. А если меньше, то ничего не происходит.  **>= 51** примерно ))) Напишите, как это будет правильно сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну оно падает потому что в стринге может быть меньше символов. Поэтому прежде чем кромсать стринг, неплохо бы условие поставить. Вы об этом сами писали в своем вопросе:

```
NSString *string = [yourLabel text];
if(string.length > 50) {
    [yourLabel setText: [string substringToIndex: 51]];
}
```

Почему 51, а не 50 - потому что substringToIndex возвращает все ДО указанного индекса, но НЕ включая его. Поэтому в условии 50, а внутри - 51.

Comment: :* прям спасатель)